# Unable to call parent's method in child React Native

Tags: react-native

I need to call my parent's onPress method, where I call my navigations props, in my child component but doesn't work. I know there is a lot of similar subject, but among those I found no one worked in my case.

Parent:

```
class Parent extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.onPress = this.onPress.bind(this)
        
    }

    onPress() {
        console.log(this.props)
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Play')
    }


    render(){
        return(
            <Child setLevel={this.props.setLevel} navigation = {()=>this.onPress()}/>
             
        )
    }
}
```

Child:

```
class Child extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.onPress = this.onPress.bind(this)
    }

    onPress(level) {
        this.props.onPress
        this.props.setLevel(level)
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <View style={styles.container}>
                {levels.map(
                x =>  { return (
                    <View style = {styles.level} key={'level' + x+1}>
                        <TouchableHighlight onPress = {() => this.onPress(x + 1)}>
                            <Text>{x + 1}</Text>
                        </ TouchableHighlight>
                    </View>
                )
                }
            )
    }
            </View>
            
        )
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two mistakes.

First you didn't pass `onPress` as prop to `Child`.

Second You have to call `onPress` in `Child` like this:

```
this.props.onPress();
```

So in `Parent` you have change it like this:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <Child setLevel={this.props.setLevel} onPress={() => this.onPress()} />
    );
  }
```

and in `Child`:

```
  onPress(level) {
    this.props.onPress();
    this.props.setLevel(level);
  }
```